# ALE not working despite passing correct flags to the enabled linters

Tags: vim, c, manjaro, i3-window-manager, vim-plugins

I'm using VIM to program in C11.

I'm trying to setup [ALE](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) but it seems that the linters can't find the headers, despite the correct flags are passed, such as `-I /path/to/include`.

I'm using CMake, so I've exported the compile commands, and configured ALE to read them, and it even show the correct flags in the ALEInfo, but it still can't find headers, so the entire project is polluted with errors.

I know that the code works because it compiles and all the tests pass.

**Distro**

```
$ neofetch
Manjaro Linux x86_64
5.3.0-1-MANJARO
Terminal: urxvt
Terminal Font: Fira Code Retina
```

**Window Manager**

```
$ i3 -v
i3 version 4.17.1 (2019-08-30)
```

**VIM**

```
$ vim
:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Aug 21 2019 18:00:45)
Included patches: 1-1906
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI
```

**.vimrc**

```
set number
set linebreak
set showbreak=+++
set textwidth=100
set showmatch
set visualbell

set hlsearch
set smartcase
set ignorecase
set incsearch

set autoindent
set cindent
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set smarttab
set softtabstop=4

set confirm
set ruler

set undolevels=1000
set backspace=indent,eol,start

set noshowmode

set nocompatible
filetype indent plugin on
syntax on
set wildmenu
set showcmd
set mouse=a
set encoding=UTF-8

autocmd BufEnter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif

let g:NERDTreeFileExtensionHighlightFullName = 1

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'valloric/youcompleteme'   " autocmpletion
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'      " directory tree
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'   " icons for the tree
Plug 'tmsvg/pear-tree'          " brackets pair
Plug 'w0rp/ale'                 " linters
Plug 'nanotech/jellybeans.vim'  " colorscheme
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'       " git integration
Plug 'auxiliary/vim-layout'     " i3 like layout
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'       " file/dir manager
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {'do' : 'make'}
Plug 'idanarye/vim-vebugger'

call plug#end()

function! Formatonsave()
  let l:formatdiff = 1
  pyf /usr/share/clang/clang-format.py 
endfunction
autocmd BufWritePre *.h,*.c,*.cc,*.cpp call Formatonsave()

command! HeaderGuard call fs_plugin#header_guard#HeaderGuard()


let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:webdevicons_enable_nerdtree = 1

" ALE Config
let g:ale_linter_aliases = { 'h': 'c' }
let g:ale_linters = { 'c': ['clang'] }
let g:ale_c_parse_compile_commands = 1
let g:ale_c_build_dir = 'build'
```

**ALEInfo**

You'll see, at the bottom, that clang is called with correct flags, taken from `.compile_commands.json`.

```
 Current Filetype: c
Available Linters: ['ccls', 'clang', 'clangd', 'clangtidy', 'cppcheck', 'cquery', 'flawfinder', 'gcc']
  Enabled Linters: ['clang']
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'clang-format' - Fix C/C++ and cuda files with clang-format.
  'clangtidy' - Fix C/C++ and ObjectiveC files with clang-tidy.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'uncrustify' - Fix C, C++, C#, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++, D, Java, Pawn, and VALA files with uncrustify.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_c_build_dir = ''
let g:ale_c_build_dir_names = ['build', 'bin']
let g:ale_c_clang_executable = 'clang'
let g:ale_c_clang_options = '-std=c11 -Wall'
let g:ale_c_parse_compile_commands = 1
let g:ale_c_parse_makefile = 0
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {'h': 'c'}
let g:ale_linters = {'c': ['clang']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_lsp_root = {}
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) clang
(finished - exit code 0) ['/bin/bash', '-c', '''clang'' -S -x c -fsyntax-only -iquote ''/home/<user>/shared-folders/host-source/repos/CLIB/src/allocator'' -Dclib_EXPORTS -I /home/<user>/CLIB/include -flto=thin -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -m64 -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c11 -Wall - < ''/tmp/vpTGYTG/1/default_allocator.c''']

<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
^[[1m<stdin>:10:8: ^[[0m^[[0;1;35mwarning: ^[[0m^[[1mimplicit declaration of function 'posix_memalign' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]^[[0m
    if(posix_memalign(&p, align, sz))
^[[0;1;32m       ^
^[[0m1 warning generated.
<<<OUTPUT ENDS>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A long shot: however is `clangd` in your path?

Certainly [Onivim (a neovim GUI) on Ubuntu failed to lint C](http://www.preciouschicken.com/blog/posts/configuring_oni_as_a_c_c++_ide_on_ubuntu_18_04/#3--install-clang) due to the peculiarities of `clangd` installation.  This was fixed with a symlink:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clangd clangd /usr/bin/clangd-6.0 1000`